# Stagnation or Total conditions in a pipe with moving fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In [Flow Science](http://www.flow3d.com/home/resources/cfd-101/physical-phenomena/boundary-conditions-pressure), they provide an example of boundary conditions and how to specify them for CFD simulations. The following is stated:

> **Pressure Boundary Example**
>
> For example, consider the problem of flow in a section of pipe. On the
>   one hand, if the upstream end of the computational region coincides
>   with the physical entrance to the pipe then a stagnation condition
>   should be used to represent the external ambient conditions as a large
>   reservoir of stationary fluid. On the other hand, if the upstream
>   boundary of the computing region is inside the pipe, and many
>   diameters away from the entrance, then the static pressure condition
>   would be a more reasonable approximation to flow conditions at that
>   location.

which I don't really understand, because inside the pipe, the fluid is already in motion, how come we shall use the static pressure?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is in the definition of "Static Pressure", which is given, according to the British Standards Institutions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSI_Group), as

> The pressure at a point on a body moving with the fluid

So the term "static" it is not to be intended as absence of motion.
Also, every point in a steadily flowing fluid, regardless of the fluid speed in that point, has its own static pressure .

Comment: so what's the difference between saying "a volume at total pressure" and "a volume at static pressure" ?

Comment: $P_{total} = P_{stagnation}$ if the gravity head of the fluid at a particular point in a fluid flow is zero. And $P_{stagnation} = P_{static}+P_{dynamic}$

Answer (score 0):

> > Because Static Pressure is just another way of saying pressure, but specific to fluid flow/dynamics. It is the pressure associated with something moving *with* the fluid.
> >
> > Dynamic pressure is the kinetic energy per unit volume of a fluid particle. (dynamic pressure usually only for incompressible flows - For compressible flows, try "impact pressure").
> >
> > Stagnation pressure (or pitot pressure) is the static pressure at a stagnation point in a fluid flow... aka it is the same idea as the static pressure BUT instead of there being cohesive/constant/"not changing"/"static" fluid motion ... At a stagnation point the fluid velocity is zero and all kinetic energy has been converted into pressure energy

```
**static pressure + dynamic pressure = stagnation pressure**
```